# Camera rendered view only renders a tiny square

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

First off, I'd like to say that my rendered view is working but when I try to view it from the camera perspective (by pressing 0) then only a small square gets rendered and the rest is still in solid view.

As you can see, it works as it should when **not** viewing from camera view
[image]

But when viewing from camera view, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, only a tiny square gets rendered and the rest is still in solid view.

I suspect that the camera setting is wrong and needs to get adjusted but I can't figure out which one it is. I tried deleting the camera and adding a new one but I still get the same problem.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you've accidentally pressed <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> to render a selected part of the scene, you need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> to get out